Summary statistics table in R Markdown
How can I make pretty table of summary satistics in R Markdown with .pdf output?
I'm trying this solution as.data.frame(lapply(df, summary)), as seen here, but getting the following error: Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array.
Required output would be something like different statistics as the row names, and the different variables as the column names. The transpose is also good (and actually even preferable, but I believe it is harder). (1 variable with mean + standard deviation) Example:




Variable




Mean
mu


SD
sigma




A fast and complete summary can be obtained using basicStats from fBasics package:
> library(fBasics)
> basicStats(mtcars)|> round(2)
               mpg    cyl     disp      hp   drat     wt   qsec    vs    am   gear  carb
nobs         32.00  32.00    32.00   32.00  32.00  32.00  32.00 32.00 32.00  32.00 32.00
NAs           0.00   0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00  0.00   0.00  0.00
Minimum      10.40   4.00    71.10   52.00   2.76   1.51  14.50  0.00  0.00   3.00  1.00
Maximum      33.90   8.00   472.00  335.00   4.93   5.42  22.90  1.00  1.00   5.00  8.00
1. Quartile  15.43   4.00   120.83   96.50   3.08   2.58  16.89  0.00  0.00   3.00  2.00
3. Quartile  22.80   8.00   326.00  180.00   3.92   3.61  18.90  1.00  1.00   4.00  4.00
Mean         20.09   6.19   230.72  146.69   3.60   3.22  17.85  0.44  0.41   3.69  2.81
Median       19.20   6.00   196.30  123.00   3.69   3.33  17.71  0.00  0.00   4.00  2.00
Sum         642.90 198.00  7383.10 4694.00 115.09 102.95 571.16 14.00 13.00 118.00 90.00
SE Mean       1.07   0.32    21.91   12.12   0.09   0.17   0.32  0.09  0.09   0.13  0.29
LCL Mean     17.92   5.54   186.04  121.97   3.40   2.86  17.20  0.26  0.23   3.42  2.23
UCL Mean     22.26   6.83   275.41  171.41   3.79   3.57  18.49  0.62  0.59   3.95  3.39
Variance     36.32   3.19 15360.80 4700.87   0.29   0.96   3.19  0.25  0.25   0.54  2.61
Stdev         6.03   1.79   123.94   68.56   0.53   0.98   1.79  0.50  0.50   0.74  1.62
Skewness      0.61  -0.17     0.38    0.73   0.27   0.42   0.37  0.24  0.36   0.53  1.05
Kurtosis     -0.37  -1.76    -1.21   -0.14  -0.71  -0.02   0.34 -2.00 -1.92  -1.07  1.26

If you want the default summary from base R, then you can use sapply + summary:
> sapply(mtcars, summary)|> round(2)
          mpg  cyl   disp     hp drat   wt  qsec   vs   am gear carb
Min.    10.40 4.00  71.10  52.00 2.76 1.51 14.50 0.00 0.00 3.00 1.00
1st Qu. 15.43 4.00 120.83  96.50 3.08 2.58 16.89 0.00 0.00 3.00 2.00
Median  19.20 6.00 196.30 123.00 3.70 3.33 17.71 0.00 0.00 4.00 2.00
Mean    20.09 6.19 230.72 146.69 3.60 3.22 17.85 0.44 0.41 3.69 2.81
3rd Qu. 22.80 8.00 326.00 180.00 3.92 3.61 18.90 1.00 1.00 4.00 4.00
Max.    33.90 8.00 472.00 335.00 4.93 5.42 22.90 1.00 1.00 5.00 8.00


That is insane! I wasn't familiar at all about that the fBasics package. Thank you.

(To answer the actual original question). Solution: fBasics::basicStats(df) |> kable().

I didn't know about that package.

You can create a vector before trying to convert to data frame.
names(mtcars) |> 
  lapply(
    \(column_name) {
      summary(mtcars[[column_name]]) |>
        as.vector() |> 
        as.data.frame() |>
        setNames(column_name)
    }
  ) |> 
  Reduce(
    f = \(x, y) cbind(x, y),
    x = _,  
    init = data.frame(
      stat = c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.")
    )
  )
#>      stat      mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs
#> 1    Min. 10.40000 4.0000  71.1000  52.0000 2.760000 1.51300 14.50000 0.0000
#> 2 1st Qu. 15.42500 4.0000 120.8250  96.5000 3.080000 2.58125 16.89250 0.0000
#> 3  Median 19.20000 6.0000 196.3000 123.0000 3.695000 3.32500 17.71000 0.0000
#> 4    Mean 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375
#> 5 3rd Qu. 22.80000 8.0000 326.0000 180.0000 3.920000 3.61000 18.90000 1.0000
#> 6    Max. 33.90000 8.0000 472.0000 335.0000 4.930000 5.42400 22.90000 1.0000
#>        am   gear   carb
#> 1 0.00000 3.0000 1.0000
#> 2 0.00000 3.0000 2.0000
#> 3 0.00000 4.0000 2.0000
#> 4 0.40625 3.6875 2.8125
#> 5 1.00000 4.0000 4.0000
#> 6 1.00000 5.0000 8.0000

This is another option
mtcars |>
  lapply(
    \(column) {
      summary(column) |> 
        as.matrix() |> 
        t() |> 
        as.data.frame()
    }
  ) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "variable")
#>    variable   Min.   1st Qu.  Median       Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
#> 1       mpg 10.400  15.42500  19.200  20.090625   22.80  33.900
#> 2       cyl  4.000   4.00000   6.000   6.187500    8.00   8.000
#> 3      disp 71.100 120.82500 196.300 230.721875  326.00 472.000
#> 4        hp 52.000  96.50000 123.000 146.687500  180.00 335.000
#> 5      drat  2.760   3.08000   3.695   3.596563    3.92   4.930
#> 6        wt  1.513   2.58125   3.325   3.217250    3.61   5.424
#> 7      qsec 14.500  16.89250  17.710  17.848750   18.90  22.900
#> 8        vs  0.000   0.00000   0.000   0.437500    1.00   1.000
#> 9        am  0.000   0.00000   0.000   0.406250    1.00   1.000
#> 10     gear  3.000   3.00000   4.000   3.687500    4.00   5.000
#> 11     carb  1.000   2.00000   2.000   2.812500    4.00   8.000

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.0.2
